# File size increases a lot after `shuf`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, shuffle

I was trying to shuffle the file by `shuf file_a.txt > file_b.txt`, but when checking, I really the `file_b.txt` has much larger size while they have exactly the same number of lines:

```
$ du -h file_a.txt file_b.txt
5.4G    file_a.txt 
13G     file_b.txt

$ wc -l file_a.txt file_b.txt
9420310    file_a.txt 
9420310    file_b.txt
```

Note that the content of `file_a.txt` looks like this:

```
part_a1   part_b1 
part_a1   part_b2
part_a1   part_b3
...
part_a2   part_b1
part_a2   part_b2
...
```

so comparing with the shuffled `file_b.txt`, `file_a` is much more ordered. I wonder if this could be the reason? But I also thought the .txt are just saved in plain format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect `file_a.txt` has gaps in it, but that's unusual for text files. How was the file created?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: ah thanks! i'll copy the question to there

Comment: but just asking, "has gap" in it mean there are lots of empty lines in the file? the file was created basically by joining the `part_an` file and `part_bn` file together.

Comment: Gaps are large blocks of zero bytes. The filesystem doesn't store blocks that are all zero.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Answer (score 0):

Find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285392/why-does-size-increase-after-i-copy) when trying to move the question to Unix & Linux. Thanks for the suggestion in the comments!